# How to use count and sum on multiple same type data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a mySQL query to get same type of data. Here is a demo data:

[image]

I want sum of maxachive and count of child_id on the basis of same type of grade and country.
e.g I want 'grade 3' total user and sum of maxachive for country AU.

Here is my desire output:

[image]

Your help will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff But how can I apply 'group by' on grade and country at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
 select sum(maxachive), count(child_id), grade, country
group by grade, country;
```

Comment: You are welcome, can you make the answer right, so that others would be helpful